# Parallel heptatonic modes ordered by changing one pitch at a time by half step in circle of fifths order

Tags: theory, scales, modes

The major scale has a property, where we can arrange all of its modes in such a way where consecutive modes differ by only one note which itself only differs by one half step

- Locrian
- Phrygian
- Aeolian
- Dorian
- Mixolydian
- Ionian
- Lydian

Every time we move down one step on that list, we change a single note and it is predictable. They move down fifths. 7 - 3 - 6 - 2 - 5 - 1 - 4. Also the note that’s changing is moving by a fifth for instance to go down the list from locrian we would #5 - #2 - #6 - #3 - #7 - #4.

Basically, my question is are there any other scales that have this property? Modes should be arrangeable in such a way where you change a single note each time you move down the list, and it should be predictable, moving in the circle of fifths.

I’m not only interested in commonly used scales. I’m wondering if it is possible to create such a scale given the constraints, or if the major scale is the only possible scale with these properties. My question is primarily about seven note scales although I would be interested in other amounts as well.

### Edit:

- As mentioned in the comments, all other modes of the major scale also have this property. I am not counting them.
- I removed references to lightness and darkness as they added confusion

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147899/discussion-on-question-by-zachiah-parallel-heptatonic-modes-ordered-by-changing); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Check out this earlier question: https://music.stackexchange.com/q/97786/9426

Comment: This question should not have been closed.  As it is currently worded, there is nothing opinion-based.  It's actually more of a math question but is still relevant to music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

The modes derived from ionian are the only possible scales fitting the conditions given in the OP.

---

## Proof

Assume that we are working within the standard 12-TET system. (This is an unstated but implicit assumption of the OP.)

**Definition:** Scale A is **brighter** than scale B iff all notes in scale A are either equivalent to or a semitone higher than the notes in B.

**Conjecture:** There exists a heptatonic scale other than those derived from ionian, such that, by sharping successive notes in the scale, in circle-of-fifths order, the modes of that scale may be ordered by brightness.

#### Proof

Suppose we are given a "home" scale with the properties assumed in the conjecture.

**Lemma 1:** The only possible sharping order, by scale degree, is `^5 ^2 ^6 ^3 ^7 ^4`.
**Proof:** Since we are to maintain a circle-of-fifths sharping order, any other ordering would necessitate sharping the scale root, because ^4 would no longer be the final pitch to be sharped, and ^1 would be next in the circle-of-fifths order.

**Lemma 2:** Suppose the next pitch to be sharped is `^X`. The interval between `^X` and `^(X+1)` cannot be a half step.
**Proof:** If it were, then sharping `^X` would create an enharmonic equivalence when sharped; i.e., the same absolute pitch would occur twice within the scale. (It is another unstated but implicit assumption that each absolute pitch is a scale occurs only once.)

**Lemma 3:** The interval between scale degrees `^5–^6`, `^2–^3`, `^6–^7`, `^3–^4`, and `^7–^1` must be greater than a semitone.
**Proof:**

- `^5` is the first sharped pitch, so `^6` must be more than a semitone higher in order to avoid an enharmonic equivalence.
- `^2` is the next sharped pitch, so `^3` must be more than a semitone higher.
- By continuing this logic, we have that the interval between scale degrees `^5–^6`, `^2–^3`, `^6–^7`, `^3–^4`, and `^7–^1` must be greater than a semitone.

**Lemma 4:** The most compact possible scale fitting our criteria must contain exactly five whole steps and two semitones.
**Proof:** It follows from Lemma 3 that there must be five intervals greater than a semitone. Therefore the most compact possible scale would have 5 whole steps. Since 5 whole steps span 10 semitones, and since there are only 12 semitones within the octave, the remaining two steps in the scale (since we're building a heptatonic scale) can only be 2 semitones.

**Lemma 5:** The only possible locations for the two semitones are at `^1–^2` and `^4–^5`.
**Proof:** This is a direct consequence of Lemma 3.

**Therefore:** It follows from Lemma 3 and Lemma 5 that the most compact possible scale meeting the given conditions can only have the interval sequence HWWHWWW, which is exactly the locrian scale.

**Lemma 6:** No scale containing an interval larger than a whole step can meet the given criteria.
**Proof:** Suppose our scale contains an interval larger than a whole step. The most compact possible scale would contain exactly one augmented second. By definition, our scale must contain seven intervals, and we know by Lemma 3 that there must be five pitches of at least a semitone. Therefore, without regard to order, our compact scale must contain at least four whole tones and exactly one augmented second. Adding the sizes of these five intervals gives `2+2+2+2+3 = 11` semitones. However, we need seven total intervals making up 12 semitones. This is not possible within the standard 12-TET system.

**Flatting all notes:** It is stated without proof that the definition of "brightness" could be changed such that sharping notes is replaced by flatting notes. Thus, this proof also applies to the case in which all notes of the home scale are changed by flatting.

**Mixed sharping/flatting:** Further, a case in which some notes are sharped and other flatted is even more restrictive than the case given in this proof, because there is further restriction on the placement of half steps.

## Therefore

The most compact possible scale meeting the criteria is equivalent to locrian, and no larger scale (i.e., no scale containing an interval larger than a whole step) can be constructed to meet the given criteria.

Comment: Temperament is not relevant; this proof holds for the 12-tone pitch system regardless of how the tones are tuned.  (Also, the characterization of the modes as being "derived from Ionian" is arbitrary; thy could just as well be described as being derived from Locrian or from any other of the modes as the "parent" mode.  But this unnecessary element is part of the question's premise, not a fault of this answer.)

Comment: What about the pentatonic scale? See my comment

Comment: @Aaron Thanks! This is exactly the answer I was looking for (at least for 7 degree scales). I ran a computer program to find these and the only ones it found were the major scale and the pentatonic scale (ignoring modes of course). So it seems that a similar argument could be made in a more general way. I am going to try doing some searches outside of 12-TET and see if I can find anything interesting as well

Comment: Also @Aaron. Should I have asked this question on Math? I knew it would be very math based but I figured most theory is so I posted it here anyways

Comment: @Zachiah I think it's a valid music question; this answer just happens to have a mathematical framing. Glad to have helped.

Comment: @Zachiah how will you define "sharpen" and "circle of fifths order" for your search outside of the 12-tone system?

Comment: @phoog Well I am going to define "sharpen" as moving up one note where note is the smallest possible value in the tuning (so if I was in 24 TET one note would be a quarter tone). I'm not particularly concerned about the "circle of fifths order" part, but my intuition tells me that it mostly can only happen on the circle of fifths. This may be a case of the XY problem. I am considering updating my question to relax this although I'm hesitant because of this great existing answer

Comment: @Zachiah Your question could be safely relaxed, at least up to a point, because I've addressed the flatting and mixed sharp/flat cases. I've not addressed non-circle-of-fifths ordering or non-12-TET systems, so that would be a step beyond the current answer.